# RStudio fatal error while generating matrix

Tags: r, matrix, levenshtein-distance

I'm processing 2 char vectors with the outer function, that results in a matrix. I'm using a Levensthein function, that compares 2 strings and outputs the simialirity of them, for each item from the vectors.

For tests with a 1000x1000 vectors, it runs fine. It runs in 4.95 sec.

```
 calc_levensthein_D <- function(vector1,vector2){

   #total matrix
   total <- as.matrix(outer(vector1,vector2,levenshteinSim))

   return(total)
 }
```

However with a 10000x5000 vector, I get a Fatal Error Message, at the ending of the processament.

Here are some tests:

~1000x1000 -> 4~6 sec

~1000x5000 -> 40~60 sec

~10000x1000 -> 688 sec ~ 11min

~10000x5000 -> fatal error after about 2hours

It's a memory problem? Any ideias? My goal is to process a 120000x10000 matrix.

OBS: The levenshteinSim is from the Record Linkage package.

Comment: Yes, it's probable that you don't have sufficient RAM. You should do this in chunks.